Calculate transformer secondary min voltage
I have this basic circuit 
supplying a fixed current load Y. Suppose that

F  = main frequency
Lv = voltage loss across diodes
Zt = impedance of the transformer
Rp = resistance of the transformer primary
Rs = resistance of the transformer secondary
C  = capacitance before the load in F
Y  = constant current load in A
Vmin = output voltage at the minimum of the ripple cycle

I was asked to calculate the output/secondary voltage of the transformer to ensure Vmin given the rest of the parameters above. Vmin is the minimum voltage achieved the the output of the PSU during the ripple up and downs.
How do I use all this data to answer to this problem?

Welcome! You will need the minimum turns ratio, primary and secondary coil resistance and leakage inductance too, depending on how accurate/worst case scenario answer you need.

Why not use a simulator?

I am supposed to have resistence of primary/secondary, I'll edit the question above. Not sure about the leakage inductance, does it contribute to the worst case result a lot?

any suggestion for an easy to use simulator?

Depends on the transformer. If tight controlled low leakage is specified, very little. If unknown, could be very much.

You could see this, pages 118 ... 123  http://www.introni.it/pdf/Motorola%20-%20Rectifier%20Applications%20Handbook.pdf

The primary and secondary resistances and impedance and leakage inductance don't actually figure into the calculation if your homework question is to provide the actual voltage present at the transformer secondary. Consider them misdirection.
You can further simplify the problem by assuming the capacitor is charged to the peak voltage minus diode drops instantaneously at the mains peaks. The pedagogues have already simplified the load to a constant current.
That should be more than enough of a hint for you to figure it out.
Generally, in this venue, it is preferred that you show your work and ask for help only if you get stuck (or for confirmation that your answer looks correct). Fully answering hw problems is frowned upon since it interferes with learning.
You can use CircuitLab (built in to the questions here), LTspice (free to download) or other simulators to check your work.
